# Azure Search json blob indexing speed

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

When using an azure search indexer to pull json blobs from a storage container into a straightforward index I'm getting throughput of ~1000 documents/minute (on the standard tier). The number of partitions has no effect. Is this around what I should expect per blob storage indexer?

I need significantly faster throughput, so should I be considering rolling my own indexer and batching calls through the rest api?

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm, are you using `"parsingMode": "json"` configuration? 
If so, you can likely significantly improve performance by increasing indexer batch size. The default batch size is `10` and is too low if your documents are small; try increasing it to 1000 (the max allowed). You can increase the batch size in the Azure portal (edit indexer blade) or programmatically using the [.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.indexingparameters.batchsize?view=azuresearch-3.0.2) or [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer) (search for `batchSize`).

If the performance still doesn't meet your requirements, you can often increase indexer throughput by partitioning your input data and creating multiple datasource / indexer pairs all writing into the same target search index (service will multiple partitions will be really handy in this case).

And of course, you can still use push API to have full control over the timing and batching of your indexing requests.

Comment: Yes I am using json parsing mode. My documents are small so I increased the batchSize to 1000. Unfortunately the performance only increased marginally.

Comment: If you email me your service name, we'll take a  look at the telemetry to see if we can make other suggestions. eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain. Rolling your own code that downloads a bunch of blobs in parallel and indexes them in a batch will likely outperform anything we do, since you can fine tune all the batch sizes and also avoid JSON parsing if unnecessary.